# Jquery my photo keeps jumping when i try to give it a different css to change to when it hits a specific scrolling number

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I scroll down I have a logo spin in 1 spot until it hits 600 on my console.log then it starts to slide to the right.The problem is when it hits 600 instead of the logo starting to slide it teleports to 600 instead if it makes sense.

```
        var $win = $(window);
         var $jet = $('#jet');


        $win.on('scroll',function(){
          var top = $win.scrollTop();

         if ($(window).scrollTop() < 600) {
         console.log($win.scrollTop())
            $jet.css('transform', 'rotate(' + top +'deg)');

            }

         if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {console.log($win.scrollTop())
            $jet.css('transform', 'translateX(' + top +'px)');}


           });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last if statement, you are just setting the immediate css styles to kick-in rather than animating to that end state.

In your last if statement, instead of:

```
$jet.css('transform', 'translateX(' + top + 'px');
```

try:

```
$jet.animate({
  transform: 'translateX(' + top + 'px)'
}, 5000, "linear", function() {
  // any javascript to apply immediately as animation completes
});
```

This will linearly move the object horizontally by "top" pixels over the course of 5 seconds.

See the [API documentation page for more information about the jQuery Animate function](http://For%20more%20information%20about%20the%20jQuery%20Animate%20function).